# Angularjs modal dialog form not recognizing click event from Datepair

Tags: angularjs

I'm using bootstrap modal with angularjs along with datepair.

http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/

I'm working on creating a single page leave request calendar where I can add leave request to the calendar via a modal dialog box. When the box pops up, you pick your date and time you'll be absent from work. I'm experiencing an issue where the datepair doesn't work when nested within the modal dialog template.

The modal dialog works in the following code, but a click doesn't seem to trigger the calendar or time popup like in the demo link provided above. Everything works fine outside of the angularjs / modal template.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

//Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
//It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

    $http.get('./requestType.json')
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.requestTypeList = data;
    });

    // initialize input widgets first
    $('#requestForm .time').timepicker({
        'showDuration': true,
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
    });

    $('#requestForm .date').datepicker({
        'format': 'm/d/yyyy',
        'autoclose': true
    });

    // initialize datepair
    var requestForm = document.getElementById('requestForm');
    var datepair = new Datepair(requestForm);


    $scope.ok = function () {
     $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
     $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

html

```
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form ng-submit="submitForm()" form-autofill-fix name="form">
                                        <p id="requestForm">    
                                            <label>Request Type</label>
                                            <select ng-model="formData.requestType" ng-options="rt.name for rt in requestTypeList track by rt.id" required class="form-control">
                                                <option value="">- Select Request Type</option>
                                            </select>      
                                            <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" class="form-control date start" ng-model="formData.startDate" required/>                                    
                                            <label>Start Time</label> <input type="text" class="form-control time start" ng-model="formData.startTime" required/>
                                            <label>End Time</label><input type="text" class="form-control time end" ng-model="formData.endTime" required/>
                                            <label>End Date</label><input type="text" class="form-control date end" ng-model="formData.endDate" required/>
                                             <ul>
                                                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                                                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </p>                                                        
                                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Agenda" class="btn btn-success"/>
                                    </form> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>  
                </script>
```

Now requestTypeList works perfectly to load the select menu, but if I click the date field, nothing pops up. What might be wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that `ModalInstanceCtrl` is executing before template inserted to the DOM. The first rule of angular: *do not work with DOM outside directive*. Try to create directive which will do `element.timepicker(...)` from its `link` function. Then you can place this directive to any input you wish. Or you can use [existent](https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker) module which doing exactly the same.

Comment: @djxak I believe you are 100% correct. I get the following error when it can't find the dom elements. Error: this.container is null
Datepair@http://localhost:8080/leave_request/assets/datepair.js?compile=false:83:3. I'm not sure I understand how to fix this though, could you please elaborate a bit more on your solution or post an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `ModalInstanceCtrl` is executing before template inserted to the DOM. The first rule of angular: <s>do not use angular</s> *do not do DOM Manipulations from controllers, services or anywhere else but from directives*.

So instead of doing this

```
$('#requestForm .time').timepicker({
    'showDuration': true,
    'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
});
```

from modal's controller make an directive for this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

    angular
      .module('xp-timepicker', [])
      .directive('xpTimepicker', timepicker);

    function timepicker() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.timepicker({
            showDuration: true,
            timeFormat: 'g:ia'
          });
        }
      };
    }
}());


// to use your directive in your app include it's module as dependency for your app module
angular
  .module('app', ['xp-timepicker']);
```

Then place this directive on input fields you need:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="time" xp-timepicker>
```

I made a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QUzTZPj2wHAur0GfvopL?p=preview) for you.

Comment: It looks as if we are very close, bu it appears as if the function of datepair is no longer working. If you select a start time it should automatically set an end time. That function does not appear to be working anymore. They were using the class start and end for this before. I forked your plunker example and finished setting up the eample, any thoughts on how to fix this? https://plnkr.co/edit/wFuKWhksn2qdkst3atsf?p=preview

Comment: Okay, so I'm missing the initialization code.  var requestForm = document.getElementById('requestForm');
 var datepair = new Datepair(requestForm); Would I need to initialize this code once the template has loaded, or is there a better approach?

Comment: I got it to work this way, but being unframilar with angularjs, is this the best approach. app.directive('sticky', function($timeout) {  
 return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) { 
   $timeout(function(){ 
    var requestForm = document.getElementById('requestForm');
    new Datepair(requestForm);
   }); 
 }; 
});

Comment: No of course this isn't right to do it this way. You can use `element` parameter in your directive's `postLink` function to init `Datepair`. Just place your directive on element on which you want to init it.
I've updated your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KQIsMdOAtEqzERR1TJzw?p=preview).

Comment: Okay, so if I understand this correctly, by adding xp-datepair to the element containing requestForm and passing element[0] into datepair, that would be the samething as getting the element by id from the dom, but with this way, it can only get the element once the template has been loaded. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes and also you can omit the `id` attribute of datepair div at all because you access element from directive without any selectors. With `getElementById` it also get element only once but it is not right way to work with directives. Note that `element[0]` is because `element` is jQuery element instance but `Datepair` requires the DOM element instance.

Answer (score 0):

the z-index of bootstrap modal by default is 1050
the z-index of the date widget seems to be 1000 by default
hence the date widget will be "under" the modal.

you will have to do some css fixes if you want the date widget to be visible above the modal window